# Проблема с конструктором класса

Tags: c++

Не могу понять почему не работает, и выдает ошибку.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Matrix;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    Matrix A = Matrix({{1, 2, 3}});
    Matrix B = Matrix({{4}, {5}, {6}});
    return 0;
}

class Matrix
{
public:
    vector<vector<int>> value;
    int row, col;
    Matrix(vector<vector<int>> arg)
    {
        value = arg;
        row = value.size();
        if (row) col = value[0].size();
    }
};
```

Вот и сама ошибка:

```
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp: In function 'int main()':
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:30:12: error: variable 'Matrix A' has initializer but incomplete type
     Matrix A = Matrix({{1, 2, 3}});
            ^
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:30:34: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Matrix'
     Matrix A = Matrix({{1, 2, 3}});
                                  ^
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:23:7: note: forward declaration of 'class Matrix'
 class Matrix;
       ^~~~~~
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:31:12: error: variable 'Matrix B' has initializer but incomplete type
     Matrix B = Matrix({{4}, {5}, {6}});
            ^
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:31:38: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Matrix'
     Matrix B = Matrix({{4}, {5}, {6}});
                                      ^
D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp:23:7: note: forward declaration of 'class Matrix'
 class Matrix;
       ^~~~~~
Процесс терминала "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /d /c C:\MinGW64\bin\g++.exe -g "D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).cpp" -o "D:\labs\lab 4 question (4).exe"" был завершен с кодом выхода 1.
```

Надеюсь тут мне помогут
Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Переместите определение класса до функции main. При создании экземпляров класса он должен быть уже полностью определен (complete type).

Answer (score 2):

После forward-определения класса и до его непосредственного объявления вы можете объявлять только переменные-указатели на данный класс, но не сам класс. Например:

```
class Matrix;
...

Matrix* pA;        //корректно
Matrix* pB = NULL; //корректно
Matrix C(...);     //а это уже неверно - компилятор ещё ничего не знает о структуре класса
...

class Matrix
{
public:
    ...
};
...

Matrix D(...);   //теперь знает - объявление корректно
```